# Show that $\{ x_n \} \overset{T}{\mapsto} \{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{nk} x_k \}$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Can someone help me with this question?

Let $\ell^2$ be the space of complex sequences $\{ x_1, x_2, \ldots \}$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert x_n \rvert ^2 < \infty$. If $\mu$ be Counting Measure on $\mathbb{N}$, then $\ell^2$ is $L^2(\mathbb{N}, \mu)$, and thus a Hilbert space.

Now suppose that $\{ a_{ij} \}$ is a complex multi index sequence such that $\sum_{i, j} \lvert a_{ij} \rvert ^2 < \infty$. Thus, we can define $T : \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$
\begin{equation}
\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty} \overset{T}{\mapsto} \{ x'_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}, \qquad x'_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{nk} x_k \ .
\end{equation}
Show that

1. $T$ is well defined, means that we have $\{ x'_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$,
2. $T$ is Bounded, and
3. $T$ is Compact.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I already proved number 1 and 2.

For number 2, I proved that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert x_n \rvert ^2 < 1$, then we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lvert \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{nk} x_k \rvert ^2 < \infty$.

I couldn't prove number 3 with definition of compact operators, or other equivalent definitions, such as being limit of finite-rank operators.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: $\sum_{i,j}|x_n|^2<\infty$ doesn't make sense, check your indexes of summation !!

Comment: @msteve: I edited my post and added what you want.

Comment: @Alonso Delfin: That was typing error, I correct that. Thanks.

Comment: edit please what you have done for number 2

Comment: @Peter: I edited. Thanks.

Comment: For 3 using that T is a limit of finite rank bounded operators works!

Comment: @Alonso Delfín: You are right, thanks. I am new here... Now, I know answer of my question, so should I delete this question?

Comment: I am putting an answer right now, you can compare it to see if yours is correct. I recommend to keep the question here, it might help others, and of course it is fine if you want to answer your own question and show your progress

Comment: @Alonso Delfín: Oh thats good, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing only **3)**.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define the operators $T_n: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ as follows, for each $x=\{ x_j\}_j \in \ell^2$ put
$$
T_n(x) = \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{1k} x_k, \cdots, \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{nk} x_k, 0 ,\cdots \right)
$$
By Hölder, for any $j\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{jk} x_k\right| \leq \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{jk}\right|^2 \right)^{1/2}\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^2 \right)^{1/2} =  \|x\|_2\left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{jk}\right|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
hence,
$$
\|T_n(x)\|^2_2 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{jk} x_k\right|^2 \leq \|x\|^2_2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{jk}\right|^2
$$
Thus each $T_n$ is bounded with norm $\| T_n \|^2\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left| a_{jk}\right|^2 < \infty$. Since $dim(T_n(\ell^2))=n$, all the $T_n$ are bounded operators of finite rank, and therefore they are compact operators.

Lets now consider $x \in \ell^2$ with $\| x\|_2=1$, then
$$
\|(T-T_n)(x)\|^2_2 =  \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{jk} x_k\right|^2 \leq \|x\|_2^2\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{jk}\right|^2 =\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{jk}\right|^2
$$
so, by the definition of norm of an operator, we get
$$
\|T-T_n\| = \sup_{\|x\|_2=1} \left\{\|(T-T_n)(x)\|_2 \right\} \leq \left( \sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|a_{jk}\right|^2 \right)^{1/2} \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 
$$
Therefore $\| T - T_n\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence being $T$ limit of compact operators , $T$ is indeed compact, since the space of compact operators is closed in the space of bounded ones.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @HosseinMoradiDavijani No problem I am glad to help !! And welcome to MSE!!